# Water potiental

Tags: homework, osmosis

[image]

I think solution x should be present at Z as this solution has moved out of cell causing cell to be plasmolysed but the answer is Y. How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not solution X what is going out of the cell, but the solvent (water) of solution X. 
Also, you need to keep in mind that the cell wall permeability is by far less selective than the cell membrane. This is why solution Y can diffuse freely to Z.